# Help with AMD Catalyst 15.9 and screen tearing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: graphics, ati, radeon, catalyst, tearing

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.04 with the latest AMD Catalyst 15.9 on an HP Envy 15 with an AMD Radeon HD 7750m. I am somewhat of a noob with Linux and I've found solutions that led to some screen tearing option found within the Catalyst panel, but it doesn't exist in the version 15.9. It is almost as if extra display options are missing. I found something about that pointing to the rest of the options being present within the display settings, but its not there either. I get screen tearing within Firefox webpages, and VLC, and Netflix within Chrome. I really don't want to go back to Windows, but this tearing thing is killing me. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hybrid Intel/AMD graphics, the display options will not be available in the Catalyst Control Center panel (including the "Tear Free" option which is available instead for AMD-only driven displays). For what I have understood, this is because with hybrid graphics setups the rendering job can be done by the dedicated (AMD) gpu, but compositing/displaying is always done by the integrated (Intel) gpu. I have a hybrid Intel/AMD configuration (Intel Broadwell/AMD Firepro m4150), I have the same tearing issues as yours when using the AMD gpu for rendering, I have tried Catalyst 15.3 and 15.9 drivers and...nothing. No display options in CCC. I am afraid that you have only two solutions to save your desktop from tearing: 1) using always the integrated gpu (on average intel linux drivers do a quite good job in 2d acceleration, with no tearing at all); 2) move from Catalyst to the Open Source Radeon drivers (however you will probably need to move away also from Unity and use some less "shiny" desktop environment, such as Xfce)

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere online and for me a setting in the radeon control centre (Administrative) helped to solve the issue.

Radeon Control Centre-> Display Options->Enable Teer Free Despktop to reduce tearing.

Since then I had no tearning. Ubuntu 15.10 Unity and the latest Catalyst Drivers 15.32